# Требуется ли запятая в данном предложении из киносценария «Солярис»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, и

Фраза из сценария Горенштейна и Тарковского «Солярис»:
«Он развязал узелок, нашел в нем хлеб, помидоры и огурцы и принялся жадно есть, запивая вином из бутылки».
Мне кажется, не хватает запятой перед второй «и»; предложение должно выглядеть так:
«Он развязал узелок, нашел в нем хлеб, помидоры и огурцы, и принялся жадно есть, запивая вином из бутылки».
Как правильно?
Заранее благодарен за ответы.

Comment: И кто это поставил минус за вопрос?

Comment: Spheinx, у Вас остались вопросы, сомнения? Может, нужны примеры? Спрашивайте, что непонятно.

Comment: Спасибо, Александр Стрелец! Вы меня убедили. Притом что Ваш оппонент выражался довольно аргументированно, поначалу я был на его стороне.

Comment: И Вам спасибо! Вы сейчас, скорее всего, не видите удалённый ответ и всю переписку на розовом фоне?

Comment: Не вижу, что несколько удивило...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Запятую перед вторым союзом ***и*** ставить не нужно:

*Он развязал узелок, нашел в нем хлеб, помидоры **и** огурцы **и** принялся жадно есть, запивая вином из бутылки.*

Первый союз ***и*** соединяет свои однородные члены: *хлеб, помидоры и огурцы*.
Второй – свои: *развязал, нашел и принялся есть*.

> 11. Если союз ***и*** повторяется в предложении не при однородных членах, то запятая между ними не ставится: *Рассмотреть планы и тезисы докладов и выступлений на научной конференции и своевременно напечатать их.*

Источник: [Однородные члены предложения, соединенные повторяющимися союзами](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=101).